# Can't create or declare GameObject variables in my c# script in monodevelop unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't declare or create the GameObject variable in C# unity i tried closing and opening the project restarted my PC but nothings working please help

[image]

Comment: Include the namespace and you are good

Comment: sorry i don't get it but you please explain more a bit through example?

Comment: even the Api are not declaring

Comment: Can you provide the entire .cs file please?

Comment: it's not about just one scripts all the scripts started behaving like this....i'm using monodevelop

Comment: actually i was trying to show that the vairable is not getting declared because it gets highlighted normally

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Do you have `using UnityEngine;` at the top of the file?

Comment: it's that the autoprediction for the C# in monodevelop has stopped working out of nowhere and i searched a lot but nothing seems to be working @Julxzs

Comment: Try to delete all folders and files except `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` .. especially delete `Library` and any `.csproj` and `.sln` file. Than open Unity and let it recompile the entire project .. most of the times this helped for me

Comment: @derHugo should i also delete Temp, Obj folders ?

Comment: `Obj` doesn't sound like a Unity generated folder ... `Temp` you can delete without problems

Comment: tried it but nothing changed , whenever i open monodevelop getting 5 6 notifications in Yellow tab with some parsing line error @derHugo http://prntscr.com/m6pcnj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties/Fields can only declared inside a class.

e.g.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public GameObject dialogueManager;
}
```

if you want to use it as a Component for an Gameobject you have to derive from MonoBehaviour:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dialogueManager;
}
```